# Draw.io -- get backend and integrations working

Tags: draw.io

we have modified draw.io to add a custom UX, and now would like to be able to save documents.  So far, we have just been serving the javascript from Apache, with no way to save.  There appears to be a backend in the github repo, which is written in java, but the directions on the wiki (https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/wiki/Building) are a bit confusing.

The ultimate goal is to get our customized version up and running on our server, allow multiple people to view the same drawing at the same time, and when one changes it, the others see the change (the way it works now on http://draw.io site), and to be able to save drawings (on server, or Google Drive or Dropbox) and share links to saved drawings with others.  This all works in other places, but we are unclear on how to get it working on our server.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you invoke the `war` task in the [Ant build.xml](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/blob/master/etc/build/build.xml), it will generate the war you can run on a servlet engine, like Tomcat.

The production version of draw.io actually runs on Google App Engine, you could try that.

In terms of storage, draw.io doesn't have the functionality to save on the server it's running on, only to the cloud storage options.

To save to the cloud storage option you need to setup API projects for each one needed and put the app IDs into the files for [Google Drive](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/blob/master/war/js/diagramly/DriveClient.js) and [OneDrive](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/blob/master/war/js/diagramly/OneDriveClient.js).

Comment: Thanks David :-)  This does help us in the right direction.  The question is really about us being mainly javascript people, and needing a little bit of clueing in on the magic step of making, say, Google Drive or Github work..  I see the javascript code that you pointed us to, thanks for that :-)  There does seem to be one more magic step to get that javascript to successfully connect.. you mentioned API projects..  could you clue us in a bit more about details of that?  There must be existing code around for those already..  can we grab that?  Is an example available to follow?  Thanks :-)

Comment: There's no extra files to draw.io, everything is on Github. For Google Drive, for example, you need to setup a Drive API project, following https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/enable-sdk.

Comment: Thanks David, that moves the stone a bit further..  the onus is on us to get educated on these things..  I went and created a certificate for Google OAuth..  but it's a shot in the dark..  any suggestions or links to some hand-holding on doing what it is the we need to do around these things?  Maybe even just the right search term for Google to find tutorial or whatever.  I get how to create the certificate, but the step of connecting the certificate to the draw.io code is still unclear..  Thanks for any help, man.

Comment: I'll improve the docs in the wiki rather than here to clarify the whole process. I can't promise exactly when though, I've an electron version of draw sitting here about 9 months overdue...

Comment: If you give us a way to push suggested changes to the wiki to you, we can contribute to that..  put in what we've learned so far, do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: Okay, from what we've learned, it comes down to a few places in the code where we need to insert a "credential".  One credential is obtained from Google, for integration with them.. another from Dropbox, and so on..  each service has a program and tutorial for how to get a credential that allows web apps to integrate with them.  After getting the credential, it is just a matter of inserting it into the javascript at the right place..  in war/js/diagramly/ you will find files that are labelled with the names of the service to integrate with -- one of those will be where insert the credential.

Answer (score 0):

Try a severless cloud backend in stead. Something like aws iot mqtt. This way you could focus on the app and not the backend. Another option is realtime.io. Very cheap and you should be able to integrate quickly. The nice part of aws is you could use aws lamda to do the heavy lifting of saving to cloud boxes